# Datetimepicker value cannot be stored in Access Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access-2007, datetimepicker

I am new to MS-Access and C# and I am having a problem in inserting a new record into my database from my `DateTimePicker` as the c# program is giving the following error:

> Insert into statement is not correct.

So I was wondering: how can I solve this problem?

```
private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "insert into BP (Name,DateTime,Systolic,Diastolic) VALUES('" + txt_Name.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' ," + txt_systolic.Text + "," + txt_diastolic.Text + ");";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Changes made Succesfully");
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR " + ex);
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `dateTimePicker1.Value` ?

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.  Some of your field names were poor choices, too.  DateTime is probably a reserved word, so you would have to put those in brackets: `[DateTime]`.

Comment: I have tried dateTimePicker1.Value also it didn't work also it shows the same error and thanks for the DateTime advice i changed it but its shoing an ERROR "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria"..

Comment: Don't ignore the bigger problem: use parameters.  Are all of your fields in the table text fields?

Comment: @LarsTech , My DateTime field is Date/Time and Systolic and Diastolic have numeric datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass a properly formatted string expression for your date value and use the correct Access SQL syntax, and Name is reserved word, thus:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into BP ([Name],DateTime,Systolic,Diastolic) VALUES('" + txt_Name.Text + "', #" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd hh':'mm':'ss") + "# ," + txt_systolic.Text + "," + txt_diastolic.Text + ");";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help its working properly, but how do i insert time and date together . is there any special format for it.

Comment: Yes, the time part can be included in the format - see edit.